# Execute a function on the first element matching selection using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I know `$('.test').each(testFunction);` invokes the `testFunction` for all matching `.test` elements on the page. How do I tell it to do just the first matching one.

I tried `$('.test:first').each(testFunction);` and it still seems to run for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:first` should work as you expected http://jsfiddle.net/guard/r5nUZ/

Comment: Thank you. I think i had another issue that made me think it was still running for all. That tool is great.

Comment: yes, jsfiddle is great for creating minimal examples, and for posting them with your SO questions =)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(".test").first();
```

this should select just the first element from that list. also if you are only trying to run it on one element why are you using each?

just do

```
testFuntion($(".test").first());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use the .first() function in place of .each(). Looking at the documentation http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/, that appears to be the function of choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.testFuntion = function() {
    return each( function() {
       console.log(this);
    });
    }
})( jQuery );
//$('.test:first').testFuntion();
```

or

```
$('.test').each(function(i) { 
  if ( i == 0 ) {
      testFuntion();
  }
});
```